# How to upload photo using GAE blobstore API combined with Django?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, blobstore

I know that the best way to upload to the blobstore is to use the blobstore API, so I tried to implement that, but I'm getting some weird errors that seem to suggest that I can't just embed a blobstore handler in my views.py file. Am I just going about this incorrectly?

ETA: I *am* using Django for all of my other views and templates, in case that wasn't clear. Just wanted to make sure no one thought I was importing Django stuff for no reason. I'm kinda stuck using it for this project.

Here is the error I'm currently getting:

```
AttributeError at /fileupload

'PhotoUploadHandler' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8080/fileupload
Django Version:     1.5.4
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'PhotoUploadHandler' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Exception Location:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django-1.5\django\middleware\common.py in process_response, line 106
```

Here is the file upload section in my views.py file:

```
from django import http 
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from models import Contact
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class PhotoUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
        photo = Photo(blob_key=upload.key())

        db.put(photo)

        self.response.out.write('<html><body><img class="imgpreview" src="/photo/%d"></body></html>' % photo.key().id())

    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/photo')
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
        self.response.out.write('Upload File: <input type="file" name="file">')
        self.response.out.write('<br><input type="submit" value="Upload"></form>')
        self.response.out.write('</body></html>')
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be simpler to use the django toolkit to enable support for storing files in GCS by default in django.

In your settings.py:

```
APPENGINE_TOOLKIT = {
    # ...,
    'BUCKET_NAME': 'your-bucket-name',
}
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'appengine_toolkit.storage.GoogleCloudStorage'
```

https://github.com/masci/django-appengine-toolkit

Files will then be saved/served from Google Cloud Storage automatically and transparently.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
    from models import Photo
    from < whatever db > import db

    ...

        photo.put()
```